# Need a regex to extract a portion of the string using java

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex to extract the a portion of a string after 'n' occurrences of a particular character

For example the string is : "aa/bb/cc/dd/ee/ff/gg/hh/ii/jj/kk/ll/mm/nn/oo/pp"
I need the content aa/bb/cc/dd/ee/ff

The followed the below approach but couldn't get the match. Please suggest i am wrong below

```
matcher = Pattern.compile("((?:[^/]*/){5})").matcher(regExString);
if (matcher.matches()) {
String str = matcher.group(1);
System.out.println(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    if (matcher.find()) {
        String str = matcher.group(1);
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.. It is working fine.. Can you explain the diff here for matches and find. Also, please suggest some good tutorial or website for learning regex